# Bootstrap 4 hamburger vanishes even though navbar expands later

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm working on my first website with bootstrap 4 and have some trouble with my collapsible navbar and the hamburger icon. I want to expand the navbar on medium screens, when smaller I want a hamburger icon to appear instead. 
So far the Navbar is expanding nicely when the screen reaches the wanted size. Only the Hamburger icon becomes invisible (though cilckable!) to early, I think it already disappeares on sm. So I end up with a certain viewport with no menu visible. I habe absolutely no idea what the problem could be...

I tried severeal different browsers and also several different kinds of buttons / icons and none seem to work. In Opera none of the ones I tried showed at all.

````
```html
<!-- Navigation-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-warning">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.shtml"><img src="img/schriftzug.png" width="262px"></a>

        <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler first-button" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar" aria-controls="collapsibleNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <div class="animated-icon"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
        </button>

    </div>
    <!-- Links-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
````

````
```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.first-button').on('click', function () {

      $('.animated-icon').toggleClass('open');
    });
  });</script>
````

etc.

Comment: Is there a closing tag for your nav element?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, the nav tag closes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to solve the problem. There must have been some blunder in my custom css. I didn't find the specific mistake, but I started from scratch and copied the original code back into the custom and made the same changes again - it works finde now...